# R Programming - order function not working correctly with a on column containing single and double digit numeric variables

Tags: r

So I am trying to use the order function to give me a data frame sorted by the desired outcome variable in the best function. Both the order and the best functions appear to be working fine up if there only double digit numbers in the outcome column.

The column should be ordered from 8.1 to 15.8, however the result ends up being from 10.0 to 15.8 and 8.1 to 10.0

[image: Numeric column after order function]
[image: Numeric column after order function2]

```
best <- function(state, outcome){
  setwd('C:/users/nikumar/datasciencecoursera')
  ocm <- read.csv('outcome-of-care-measures.csv', colClasses = 'character', na.strings = "Not Available", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  index <- numeric()
  if ((state %in% ocm$State) == FALSE) {
    stop("invalid state")
  }
  if (outcome == 'heart attack') {
    index <- 11
  }
  else if (outcome == 'heart failure' ) {
    index <- 17
  }
  else if (outcome == 'pneumonia') {
    index <- 23
  }
  else{
    stop("invalid outcome")
  }
  ocm1 <- ocm[ocm$State == state,]
  ocm1 <- ocm1[,c(2,7,index)]
  ocm1 <- ocm1[order(ocm1[3],ocm1[1], decreasing = FALSE),]
  ocm1 <- na.omit(ocm1)
  View(ocm1)

  ocm1[1,1]

}
```

Comment: The results are in alphabetical order. You must have strings instead of numbers. Try using `as.numeric` before sorting.

Comment: Try to find a function that could turn those strings into numeric

Comment: @G5W +1 definitely in alphabetical order.